# Why does MediaCodec.BufferInfo.presentationTimeUs from an encoding MediaCodec decrease sometimes?

Tags: android-mediacodec

An Android app encodes G.711 audio to AAC.
Here is the data input part:

```
MediaFormat mfAACEncoder = new MediaFormat();
mfAACEncoder.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
mfAACEncoder.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
mfAACEncoder.setInteger(android.media.MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, iClockRateAudio);
mfAACEncoder.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 1024 * 4);//AAC-HE 64kbps
mfAACEncoder.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64 * 1024);//AAC-HE 64kbps
mfAACEncoder.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectLC);  

MediaCodec _mcAACEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
_mcAACEncoder.configure(mfAACEncoder, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
_mcAACEncoder.start();
...
int inputBufferIndex = _mcAACEncoder.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
ByteBuffer bbInputBuffer = _inputBuffersAACEncoder[inputBufferIndex];
bbInputBuffer.clear();
bbInputBuffer.put(byteArrayData);
_mcAACEncoder.queueInputBuffer(
        inputBufferIndex,
        0, 
        byteArrayData.length,
        lPresentationTime,
        0);
```

The following is the output handling code:

```
int outputBufferIndex = _mcAACEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);
ByteBuffer bboutputBuffer = _outputBufferAACEncoder[outputBufferIndex];
logLongD("debug", "Presentation time (micro-s): " + bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs)
```

I thought bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs ought to increase monotonically but I see at least on a device it decreases sometimes. Here are a few examples:

```
decreased to (micro-s): 62156000 from 62278000
decreased to (micro-s): 62157000 from 62279000
decreased to (micro-s): 95213500 from 95335500
```

The input presentation time lPresentationTime is made sure to increase monotonically. Could anyone shed some light on the possible causes of this?